# XNA Rotate player with mouse without moving mouse pointer

Tags: xna

I want to be able to rotate my player using the mouse. I've tried the following:

```
playerYaw = (float)(-currentMouseState.X * 0.005);
```

My player rotates just the way I want it to, but I can only rotate as far as the mouse pointer will go. I want to be able to rotate my player as many times clockwise or counter clockwise as I want. How can I not take the mouse pointer into consideration and still get the result I'm looking for. Also, is there a way to hide the mouse pointer?? I shouldn't see it moving around my monitor when playing a game in windowed mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just increase your multiplier to increase rotation speed.

To hide cursor while in windowed mode, you'd have to change the system's cursor icon to invisible, if you want the cursor to leave the game window at all, but that requires going to control panel, which might be undesirable.

Alternatively, you could lock the cursor's coordinates to be always inside the game's window by setting the mouse coordinates each frame.

I'd recommend going windowed fullscreen with black borders around the game window, so you could press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> whenever you like without minimizing the game window, and still technically playing in windowed mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I lock the cursor's coordinates each frame wouldn't that technically (using the code in my question) keep the player looking in the same direction??

Comment: You will always be able to calculate cursor position delta, after which you can set the cursor's position. That's how most FPS games do it.